# Ant colony optimization using .NET

Tags: .net, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, montecarlo, ant-colony

I'm looking for a .NET-Class library or .NET-Framework which implements ant colony optimization. Can you give me any links, resources, etc. about this topic.

Comment: I don't think the `ant` tag is appropriate for this question. It is used for Apache Ant

Comment: Out of interest, what type of problem are you solving using ant colony optimisation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) has published a [short tutorial](http://activevb.de/tutorials/tut_antalgo/tut_antalgo.html) on ACO's on a german programming website.

It contains a fully-working VB.NET example project (in English) solving a Traveling Salesman Problem using an ACO.

[image: ACO map of europe]

Comment: Downloaded the source code, but could not find the map file? any help is highly appreciated.. (the language is german could not investigate any further :D)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization). It provides a good desription of the algorithm. The algorithm is rather easy to implement based on that arcicle.

[www.aco-metaheuristics.org](http://www.aco-metaheuristic.org/) provides some more info on subject.

I have implemented a  [solution to travelling salesman problen using python](http://github.com/jsyrjala/pysalesman/blob/master/salesman.py). It is not .NET but maybe it is some help for you.

Comment: Solution using python is very good. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [MSDN article by James McCaffrey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781027.aspx), I've been using a modified version of it for a while and it gave me very satisfying results. The article is  very clear and the code is very clean and efficient.